# Font-awesome in Polymer 2

Tags: font-awesome, polymer-2.x

I would like to use fontawesome icons. I have the following webcomponent but icons are not shown:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<dom-module id="mi-icono">
  <template>
    <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     */
    class MiIcono extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'mi-icono'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {};
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MiIcono.is, MiIcono);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Anyone knows why icons are not shown?

Comment: I have the same issue, if you find a solution let me know. I downvoted both answers because you're using SVG + JS FA icons (as me) and they are using pure css + webfonts, which is not your question nor in your code, pure JS... I think it has something to do with shadow-root because the JS works with icons outside any polymer dom-module..

Answer (score 1):

First, create a style import file: (import.html)

```
<link rel="import"      href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/fa-regular.min.css">

<dom-module id="font-awesome">
  <template>
    <style>
      <!-- TODO: Paste contents of fontawesome-all.css here! -->
      <!-- TODO: Update paths in pasted content to match directory structure -->
      <!-- Would be awesome to use @import here but it doesn't work? -->
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Now you can import the file in your application:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../lib/fontawesome-5.0.6/import.html">
```

Be sure to include the import anywhere you want to use the icons:

```
<dom-module id="my-super-cool-polymer-app">
  <template>
    <style include="font-awesome">
      <!-- etc -->
```

Comment: HTML imports are deprecated. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the font-awesome.css gets loaded outside your element, so the shadow dom then hides `i`s so that no document-level CSS can style it.

What works for me in polymer 2 and font-awesome 4.7, is to include the css inside the dom-module:

```
<dom-module id="demo">

<!-- this is deprecated but still works in v2:
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#external-stylesheets-->
<link rel="import" type="css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

  <template>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i>
  </template>

</dom-module>
```

Just tested it and works fine in IE (11+), FF, Safari 11, Chrome v53-, but as of Chrome v54 the caret is not properly rendered:

[image: font-awesome chrome bug]

This works ok in Chrome when font-awesome.css is also included in the main document?!